# Cloning fieldset with jQuery without keeping value for input type file

Tags: jquery, clone, file-io

How can I remove the value for an input of type file which is child of a fieldset that gets cloned with jQuery.

If the cloned object has a value already set for the file input, it will keep it.

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.technowise.in/2009/12/clear-file-input-field-using-jquery.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Updated:*

Here's a new approach using some of the tips from redsquare and Šime:

```
var $clone = $('#my-fieldset').clone(),
    $clonedFileInputs = $clone.find('input:file');

// this browser check is nasty, but I don't know how to feature-detect this...
if ($.browser.msie) {
    // avoid security error by replacing input, rather than setting value
    $clonedFileInputs.replaceWith(function() {
        return $(this).clone();
    });
} else {
    $clonedFileInputs.val('');
}

$clone.appendTo('#new-parent');
```

Comment: ... or `.find( 'input:file' )`

Comment: Just cloning the file input will reset it (in ie)

Comment: It's not doing that in FireFox 6.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer based on some of the comments.  I don't like the explicit check for IE, but I'm not sure how to feature-detect whether or not a browser will throw a security error when setting the value of a file input.